# where can i find qemu-kvm 4.2.0 for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ppa, qemu

I'm using 18.04 ubuntu, but the qemu-kvm installed is very old  (2.1) 
Is there a ppa with the last version 4.2.0?

Comment: Yes, it is old but it fits with the other parts of Ubuntu 18.04. version 4 is available in Ubuntu 19.10. So move to 19.10. I couldn't find a version 4 ppa for 18.04 at launchpad. Why do you want version 4? Doesn't what you have work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 4):

Qemu-kvm can be found on the [download page](https://www.qemu.org/download/#source) on their website. They provide instructions for a tar ball download:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://download.qemu.org/qemu-4.2.0.tar.xz
tar xvJf qemu-4.2.0.tar.xz
cd qemu-4.2.0
./configure
make
```

There is no PPA for 4.2. According to [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/qemu-kvm) there is

- [4.0 for Ubuntu 19.10](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.10/ubuntu-main-amd64/qemu-kvm_4.0+dfsg-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb.html)
- [3.1 for 19.04](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/qemu-kvm_3.1+dfsg-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb.html)

Upgrade to 19.10 if you want the latest version using Ubuntu's installation method. Or get used to installing from source. 2.1 IS the one made for 18.04.

Comment: In addition to what Rinzwind said https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive will have backports of those for the latest LTS. Ubuntu 20.04 will most likely contain 4.2 and then the CloudArchive will have a backport of it for 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

https://software.opensuse.org/package/qemu

There is a community build for Ubuntu 18.04 and other distributions

Comment: I can't find deb package on the given link. There are only RPM packages.

Comment: Yes, that's a bit unobviouse site. Click "Show for other distribution" in bottom left. And there will be community build for Ubuntu 18.04. Actually you need link https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=qemu&project=home%3Anoscript from there

You need to uninstall your official version before install this

Comment: I'd recommend you to change  the link in the post.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure it works all that well. I just installed and I see QEMU version now is `2.11.1`. For reference, latest QEMU [is 6.1.0](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qemu/)